# Power Pivot DAX formula to compare this year vs previous performance when no date column available

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a large dataset with 7M records. I have aggregated monthly data for the past 4 years and Lowest level of granularity is at month level with Month number. I need to construct a power pivot table to calculate  % difference between this year's performance (YTD) to previous year (YTD last year) on the fly. The SamePeriodLastYear and ParallelPeriod function does not work as the data is not at individual date level. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**create a date column** in your monthy data like for april 2017- 1/4/2017 take 1st date of every month

and create a **date dimention** table that will have continuos date and connect monthly data to date dimention using date column of monthly data

and in SamePeriodLastYear and ParallelPeriod function use date colun of date dimention

Comment: Thank you, I will give that a go and let you know the outcome.